# Python - Multiline SQL with List - Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql

I'm usually a C# Dev, in an attempt to get some python experience.

So at this current time I got a List of values I want to import into MYSQL, as there will be quite a few lines I want go with a single big import than thousands of small ones.

Looking at the docs on pynative I can see the example being provided as:

```
 mySql_insert_query = """INSERT INTO Laptop (Id, Name, Price, Purchase_date) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) """

    records_to_insert = [(4, 'HP Pavilion Power', 1999, '2019-01-11'),
                         (5, 'MSI WS75 9TL-496', 5799, '2019-02-27'),
                         (6, 'Microsoft Surface', 2330, '2019-07-23')]

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.executemany(mySql_insert_query, records_to_insert)
    connection.commit()
```

As my records to insert will be data pulled from an API, I had the "briliant" idea of building the list the most basic and probably the worst method possible.

By creating the list with a pre-formatted string.

```
  val = []
  sql = """INSERT INTO equipment (ItemStaticID, ItemID, ItemType, Element, Tier, Level, Hp, Atk, Hit, Def, Spd) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
  for x in range(len(test)):
    print(test[x].id, test[x].itemId, test[x].itemSubType, test[x].elementalType, test[x].grade, test[x].level, test[x].hP, test[x].aTK, test[x].hIT, test[x].dEF, test[x].sPD)
    value = "({},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(test[x].id, test[x].itemId, test[x].itemSubType, test[x].elementalType, test[x].grade, test[x].level, test[x].hP, test[x].aTK, test[x].hIT, test[x].dEF, test[x].sPD)
    print(value)
    val.append(value)  
  
  insertcur = mydb.cursor()
  insertcur.executemany(sql, val)
```

When running this code I get a "Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement", I verified that the SQL Query was accurate and the fields listed matched, 11 column names and I got 11 params.

So I'm a bit lost why it believes that not all params are being used in the SQL statement.

The below is the content of my list "val"

```
["(10340000,'d3252f40-5cbb-4a7c-a140-dcc2badac580','BELT','NORMAL','4','1','0','0','555','0','1683')", "(10340000,'e8e16a7b-4271-4cd4-8700-4dfb17a9525f','BELT','NORMAL','4','2','0','0','534','0','1848')", "(10341000,'66e70f12-f13b-4572-a222-cd61740d78b8','BELT','FIRE','4','0','0','0','503','0','1921')", "(10130000,'7cc2027b-110e-4ba0-9d95-ce563eca4be9','WEAPON','NORMAL','3','0','0','99','0','0','0')", "(10130000,'88440779-0794-431e-a726-3cb63af1dae1','WEAPON','NORMAL','3','0','0','99','0','0','0')", "(10130000,'f513afc3-9035-40b4-a0bb-6d4a74b88c7d','WEAPON','NORMAL','3','0','0','100','0','0','88')", "(10130000,'e22a771e-3fd7-4ce4-93c4-254913e89551','WEAPON','NORMAL','3','0','0','100','0','0','93')", "(10230000,'bf97a302-41e1-4b21-b7ff-3d7786f96ec3','ARMOR','NORMAL','3','0','1707','0','0','33','0')", "(10233000,'69f4811f-f45b-4227-99eb-2f45f0705c2a','ARMOR','LAND','3','0','11254','0','0','0','0')", "(10431000,'0813b427-de85-4fd6-82a1-fe8b8708ad45','NECKLACE','FIRE','3','0','0','0','677','30','0')", "(10531000,'48fc6562-44b5-49ba-8ad2-837d0e981a70','RING','FIRE','3','0','0','65','0','90','0')", "(10120000,'e5ebcdb9-ae59-4fc2-adb8-50e3b673c26d','WEAPON','NORMAL','2','0','0','39','0','0','0')", "(10120000,'22194497-91d1-405d-8a46-9c25b36c7ffd','WEAPON','NORMAL','2','1','0','42','0','0','37')", "(10124000,'487e9efc-a5f6-4944-924a-38ff8bcfb014','WEAPON','WIND','2','0','0','421','0','0','0')", "(10124000,'d015eced-58ec-48c4-bdbd-4f790c9ccbe4','WEAPON','WIND','2','0','0','453','0','0','572')", "(10124000,'1c624b33-889d-42f1-ae6b-2ddda234c481','WEAPON','WIND','2','1','0','462','0','0','0')", "(10220000,'225f94e7-2342-4a50-a1b7-07ec789457f1','ARMOR','NORMAL','2','1','737','0','0','13','0')", "(10220000,'64bd3ce5-572a-4b83-b83c-5f8f7f728f9e','ARMOR','NORMAL','2','1','727','0','0','13','0')", "(10224000,'206d6a67-3d1e-4b22-ad94-1ee19bdb4e00','ARMOR','WIND','2','3','9597','0','0','67','0')", "(10224000,'0ddc84d4-b65d-4b6d-b332-b3de72defce2','ARMOR','WIND','2','3','8972','0','0','88','0')", "(10321000,'3d0f39cb-0684-42a4-a9b0-ec2466679d18','BELT','FIRE','2','0','0','0','0','0','176')", "(10423000,'4ebb7192-15d4-4e9d-999c-be4a2e7ac85a','NECKLACE','LAND','2','3','0','0','1833','63','0')", "(10523000,'d1260941-ba0f-4a2a-b452-b3c3a6d6ec81','RING','LAND','2','0','0','0','384','172','0')", "(10523000,'fdef3e38-88ba-4970-923e-1d46ea35d1c5','RING','LAND','2','3','0','0','295','282','0')", "(10523000,'e3657fe9-481e-45ea-9086-065a79e3bc06','RING','LAND','2','0','0','0','376','173','0')", "(10523000,'68ab4ca0-683f-43a8-a2c6-358788e4e5e8','RING','LAND','2','2','0','0','408','195','0')", "(10523000,'be3921cc-fc3a-48bb-8542-c385d83d99cb','RING','LAND','2','0','0','0','0','172','0')", "(10523000,'422bb5ab-bef6-42a8-8562-a572d07c7970','RING','LAND','2','0','0','0','0','175','0')", "(10523000,'708df542-4622-4849-899c-846938f98ef2','RING','LAND','2','0','0','0','392','173','0')", "(10111000,'54896e7e-9799-4c81-a704-124522ab9b91','WEAPON','FIRE','1','3','0','23','0','0','0')", "(10210000,'09f995cd-6a8c-47ae-8c46-18f799322c9a','ARMOR','NORMAL','1','2','264','0','0','5','0')", "(10212000,'4effa256-6fe1-4051-866d-0f77d4294004','ARMOR','WATER','1','0','374','0','0','0','0')", "(10312000,'326908bb-ba10-4be9-abf2-4499d413bbb0','BELT','WATER','1','2','0','0','23','0','110')", "(10412000,'390c39f3-756b-488a-ae3f-eb03021453af','NECKLACE','WATER','1','3','0','0','156','8','0')", "(10512000,'7f8f0faf-da5c-435c-a27b-14ccbf94dd08','RING','WATER','1','3','159','0','0','20','0')", "(10514000,'08049c6d-5923-49d6-ac5f-fb569fc69ed3','RING','WIND','1','2','0','0','0','224','232')", "(10514000,'8dce0420-4d09-4ab6-8d73-86343155f8b9','RING','WIND','1','3','0','0','0','230','433')"]
```

Comment: You create list of strings, not list of tuples. Why do you create `value` with string formatting? `value = (test[x].id, test[x].itemId, test[x].itemSubType, test[x].elementalType, test[x].grade, test[x].level, test[x].hP, test[x].aTK, test[x].hIT, test[x].dEF, test[x].sPD)` should do. There might be a better way to create the tuple using the `test[x]` object. Also you can iterate over `test` elements, not using index with `range(len(test))`

Comment: Oh my god, I'm an idiot. Thanks, so many hours for something so obvious!

Appreciate your quick response.